# How to perform the transformation on CompletableFuture tasks

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency

I am trying to perform some transformation on the list of CompletableFuture tasks, but facing some issue because of lack of experience. I have a list of CompletableFuture but I am failing to perform further transformation on it.

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class thenapply {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 9, 14);

        final int sum = 0;

        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            final int finali = i;

            ans.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> square(list.get(finali))));

        }

        System.out.println(ans.stream()

                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());

    }

    private static int square(int a) {

        return a * a;

    }

}
```

I know `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` is wrong but do not know how to correct it. Further, I am reading that we should use `allOf` but I am not sure how to implement it here.

Please help.

Comment: There are [numerous methods you can use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). It could be for example `join`,  `thenAccept`, `thenAcceptAsync` etc.

Comment: `.mapToInt(CompletableFuture::join)` but you should be aware that performing parallel operations with such a granularity with `CompletableFuture` is as inefficient as complicated to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 9, 14);
    final AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int size = list.size();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        final int finali = i;
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            int sq= square(list.get(finali));
            sum.addAndGet(sq);
            latch.countDown();
        });
    }
    latch.await();
    System.out.println(sum.get());
}
```

Comment: why do we need to use `CountDownLatch `? How about doing `ans.stream().mapToInt(data->data.join).sum()`? It works but want to make sure if I want to use `allOf` and handle exceptions?

Comment: join() is blocking operation, should not be used in asynchronous code. See also @Holger's comment

Comment: If I understand correctly, `System.out.println(sum.get())`; will wait until `latch.countDown()`; has a value zero i.e. all tasks in the thread are completed. I am getting `unreported exception java.loang. InterruptedException: must be caught or declared to be thrown`. Should I add the entire block of code after `latch.await()` inside `try`?

Comment: did you add "throws InterruptedException" to the declaration of main(), as is in my text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for completion before you can do further calculation.
So, instead of your last `System.out.println`, do something along

```
// wait and process individual values
int result = 0;
for (var f : ans) {
    result += f.get();
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: `error: incompatible thrown type InterruptedException, ExecutionException` for the last line.

Comment: @Amul123 I modified my answer to accomodate for that and removed unnecessary steps.