# Processing using CompletableFuture and caching

Tags: java, hibernate, future, dao, dropwizard

With some help I was able to do asynchronous programming using Completable futures.
However, at the beginning of the application, I am creating a caching and the code is as follows:

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import org.h2.table.Plan;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class test {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class);
    private static LoadingCache<String, Plan> something;

    public static void initLoadingCache( ) {
        if (something == null) {
            something = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .concurrencyLevel(10)
                    .maximumSize(1000) // Maximum of 1000 records can be cached
                    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // Cache will expire after 60 minutes
                    .build(new CacheLoader<String, Plan>() { // Build the CacheLoader
                        @Override
                        public Plan load(String key) throws Exception{
                            Plan record = getGraphFromDB(key);
                            if (record == null)  LOGGER.error("DB {} is not present", record);
                            return record;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

`getGraphFromDB` is doing nothing but running a correct SQL query.
I observed in my logs I am getting `record` as `null` and hence, I threw the exception. Upon further investigation I found that I am getting `No session currently bound to execution context`  as the Error. I added `@UnitOfWork` in the beginning of the method where I am performing the Async processing using Completable Future ([How to perform the transformation on CompletableFuture tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805486/how-to-perform-the-transformation-on-completablefuture-tasks)). The problem still persists and I cannot find out why it is happening.

Update based on the comment:

```
public Plan getGraphFromDB(String key) throws Exception{

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {
            ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            try {
                return somequery(key);
                transaction.commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
            ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you do asynchronous operation in your `CompletableFuture`, the database query is running on a different thread than the one you are triggering it from. The problem is, Hibernate sessions are not thread-safe (needed 1 per thread). In the thread that is executing the query, you do not have a hibernate session in the context. See this answer for more info on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037848/1005102

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Added the code but still have the same issue. One thing that I want to ask is that do I need to put the manual session code for all queries or just for the ones which I am using? Why the issue is still there?

Comment: I do not know the internals of DropWizard and its integration with Hibernate, but as a rule of thumb, whenever a database query need to be executed from your code, at that moment there must be a Hibernate session in that context.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir yes, but I think I just provided the sessions I think in the query which is being used. The code is updated as well. Any issues there?